# Can Animals Be Affected By Ruach Ra’ah

Tags: animals, netilat-yadayim-washing, ruach-rah

Can a person’s animal be affected by Ruach ra’ah  if one touches their pet’s mouth or the inside of their ear before doing morning netilat yadayim?

Comment: Based on the edit to a previous question you asked, it would seem that they can be affected, according to the way the Dirshu understands the MB

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/130092/27180